# Don't know how to add loop to my program...?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Okay I was told to write a rock/paper/scissors game using "switch statements." I finished that, but today in class we were asked to add a loop to our existing game.
I understand the basics about for loops and while loops, however I don't understand how to add them to an existing program. 
Which one is better to use? And what do I do?

Thanks guys

So again, I understand the basics of for loops and while loops. But I don't understand if there is anything else I need to declare, what I need to input to receive the correct output/loop.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{ // opening bracket 

    int game;
    cout <<"Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors \nEnter 1 for rock, 2 for paper,3 for scissors"<< endl ;

    cin >> game;

    switch(game)
    {
            case 1:
                    cout << "You chose rock" << endl;
                    break;
            case 2:
                    cout << "You chose paper" << endl;
                    break;
            case 3:
                    cout << "You chose scissors" << endl;
                    break;
            default:
                    cout<<game << " is not a valid choice"<< endl;
    }

} // closing bracket
```

BELOW IS MY PROFESSOR'S INSTRUCTIONS:

Create the second part of a Rock, Paper, Scissors game.  Enhance lab 5 so that the user keeps playing as long as they enter in 'Y'.  Make this case sensitve; if they enter a lower case y the game will not continue.  If the user enters in anything besides upper case Y the game will end.

Your text must exatly match the examples below:

Example 1 with correct input
Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors
2
You chose paper
Would you like to play again (Y for yes, N for no)?
Y
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors
1
You chose rock
Would you like to play again (Y for yes, N for no)?
N
Example 2 with incorrect input
Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors
5
5 is not a valid choice
Would you like to play again (Y for yes, N for no)?
y

Comment: Your professor's instructions are pretty straight forward, if you understand loops then enclose your game logic in a loop so the game can continue being played. (this is typically called a game-loop)

If you have trouble, update your code with what you have done.I would also suggest adding a score counter and a random number generator for the computer player. 

Also I would avoid asking for solutions to Uni tutorials.

Comment: @Slipoch well my problem is that I'm still learning the terminologies of what variable goes where, etc. And when it comes to loops I understand some of the formation, however I am completely lost on how to input the loop correctly into a program.

Comment: Well inside any loop's braces you put any of the logic you wish to loop through.
The answer below by @solarflare is exactly this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably best for you to watch some youtube videos or read up on basics about loops. Anyways, here is a very simple way to understand this

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    char choice = 'Y';

    //enter this loop since 'choice' equals Y
    while(choice == 'Y'){

        //run the game

        //if they enter anything else other than Y, it will stop the loop
        std::cout << "Would you like to play again (Y for yes, N for no)? \n";
        std::cin >> choice;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow this one really helps. And I've been watching youtube videos, but all I could grasp from the videos was that you always have to put "while", some sort of variable, if its equal to/greater/etc, and a value...for ex: "while(variable<=10)"   .... thats what was confusing me. I didn't know what to input for my code.    But thanks a lot man. This really helped

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have now:

```
//some code that plays a game
```

Here is what you want:

```
while player wishes to continue playing
  //same code that plays the game
end while
```

or alternatively use a for loop but exiting that will be different, you will need to "break" out of it.

Comment: Your idea is great, but are you sure the OP will not copy your code verbatim? ;)

Comment: @L.F. If he does and it works I hope he credits me for my hard work

Comment: I hope you are not joking ;)

Comment: I'd probably do a do {} while instead of while {}, if the user starts the game I would assume they want o play at least one round.

Comment: while{} will work perfectly fine if you put in the iteration condition at the bottom of the loop and initialise it with a negative value outside the loop.  And it looks neater in my opinion.

Comment: @solarflare you could of introduced him to `Labels`, `goto` and `macros` lol!

Comment: @FrancisCugler goto is a perfectly acceptable way of writing code, we sent men to the moon using goto commands

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also make use of infinite loop to make it work.

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()

    { // opening bracket 

        int game;

        while(1) //you can comment this line and uncomment below line rest all will be same
        //for(;;) 
        {
            cout << "\nLet's play Rock, Paper, Scissors \n Enter \"1\" for rock\n Enter \"2\" for paper\n Enter \"3\" for scissors\n **Press any other key to exit from the game." << endl ;
            cout << "\nYour option is : ";  
            cin >> game;

            switch(game)
            {
                    case 1:
                            cout << "You chose rock\n" << endl;
                            break;
                    case 2:
                            cout << "You chose paper\n" << endl;
                            break;
                    case 3:
                            cout << "You chose scissors\n" << endl;
                            break;
                    default:
                            cout << game << " is not a valid choice\n"<< endl;
                            return 0;
            }
        }

    } // closing bracket
```